# Creating .hashcode() and .equals() methods for a large object

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have a class with many (about 100) fields. I want to implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods for these fields, is there any alternative to doing this manually?

Comment: 100 is a crazy amount of fields for a single class... consider refactoring.

Comment: eclipse can auto generate those methods for you

Comment: You should first re-write your class. I can't think of any entity except GOD to have 100 attributes of its own ;-)

Comment: im not a fan of eclipse or spamming fields either, just pointing out if OP wasn't aware.

Comment: what are your 100 fields?? Are they all the same type?

Comment: different data types  mohsaied..!!

Comment: are they all objects? you can store them in a HashMap<String,Object>

Answer (score 4):

There's no great answer.  Here are a few suggestions.  As others have commented, 100 fields are far too many.  You best bet is to refactor the class.  But, if you must keep it all together:

- **Could you use a *Map* (or other Collection) to hold many of the fields?**

If so, you can use their built in hashCode() and equals() methods.  (Or Guava etc. as pointed out by @dimo414)

- **hashcode() should only consider immutable fields** (or at least fields that seldom seldom change.)

If only a few of your fields are immutable, that will greatly simplify your `hashCode()` code.  And, more importantly, make it correct.  :-)

- **With 100+ fields, what's the realistic chance that two instances will *ever* be equal?**

If the answer is "extremely rarely", ask yourself if you could get away with using the basic Object equality (in effect, using  ==)?

- **Do you already have an informative *toString()* method?**

If so, you can *sometimes* use that String as an inefficient, but easy to code, hashCode() and equals().  e.g.:

```
public int hashCode() { return this.toString().hashCode(); }

public boolean equals(Object o) {
   return (o instanceof MyClass) &&
          (this.toString().equals(o.toString()));
}
```

Comment: If modifying an object changes the set of other objects to which it could compare equal, it's fine for such modification to affect the `hashCode()` value. It is in general illegitimate for objects to store a reference to something into a map and then--while the map still holds the reference, modify it in such a way that it would either compare equal to things which it didn't previously, or vice versa. Although it would be possible for code to modify objects stored in a map without running afoul of the above limitation if they knew that the map would never see two objects compare equal...

Comment: ...at one time and unequal at some other time, and having the hash code change would break the map in a situation where having the hash code stay the same would have worked, most code which uses maps properly shouldn't care if changes that affect equality also affect the hash code.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out that an object this large is likely not a great pattern to follow, so I'll assume you know that already and have decided to proceed anyways.  I'm also going to assume this object is (mostly) immutable, since implementing `.hashCode()` for mutable objects is generally a bad plan (at the very least, you have to be careful about putting mutable objects in a `HashSet` or as keys in a `HashMap`).

If you have a class with a large number of fields you can avoid defining complex `.hashCode()`, `.equals()`, and `.toString()` methods by taking advantage of existing functionality that does the same thing.  An easy option is to construct a `List` or `Map` of your fields, and simply call the respective methods of that `Collection`.  You can even cache the return values of these functions, rather than hold onto the whole `Collection`, if you want.

There are also many useful utilities to make these methods easier; there's way too many to list, but I'll try to call out a couple of particularly useful ones:

- **Stock JDK:**

  - Hashing: [`Objects.hash()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash(java.lang.Object...)), [`Arrays.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode(java.lang.Object[]))
  - Equals: [`Arrays.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]))
  - ToString: [`Arrays.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[]))
- **[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):**

  - Hashing: [`Hashing.combineOrdered()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/master/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html#combineOrdered(java.lang.Iterable)) and a whole batch of powerful [hashing utilities](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/HashingExplained).
  - Equals: [`Iterables.elementsEqual()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#elementsEqual(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable))
  - ToString: [`MoreObjects.toStringHelper()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#toStringHelper(java.lang.Object))
- **[AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value):** Awesome tool, does everything you want for you as long as your object is conceptually a value type.

Additionally, you could [use reflection to get all the fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html) in your object at runtime.  This would be slower than a hard-coded implementation, but it would likely be faster to write.  If you aren't overly concerned about speed, this is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I think It is better to use the *eclipse functionality* to generating code for `hashCode()` and `equals()` which does a pretty good job for implementing this methods.

Comment: Generating a hashcode on all 100+ fields is almost certainly wrong, as many will be mutable.  I guess you could use Eclipse to start, then delete many of them.

Comment: @user949300 yes eclipse will easily create code then we will easily manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a good practice to have an object with that many fields, sometimes legacy constraints trap you in a bad situation.

Regardless of size, I find the easiest way to override these methods is by using the Apache commons library. It uses reflection to generate the values from the instance and there are a number of ways to configure the results. I also never have to remember to regenerate the method if the fields update, unlike the eclipse generated methods.

```
@Override
public final boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }

    if(obj != null && obj.getClass() == this.getClass()) {
        return EqualsBuilder.relectionEquals(this, obj, true);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public final int hashCode() {
    return HashCodeBuilder.relectionHashCode(this);
}

@Override
public final String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE);
}
```